# Bot edit its own message after a period of time

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this piece of code, however, the bot is not editing its message after the `time.milliseconds * 1000` time. How could I possibly task the bot to edit its message after that period of time?

```js
let timeout = 15000;

if (author !== null && timeout - (Date.now() - author) > 0) {
   let time = ms(timeout - (Date.now() - author));
          
    return await message.channel.send("Cool down in effect").then((msg) = {
        setTimeout(() => msg.edit("Cool down is over"), time.milliseconds * 1000)
    })
}
```

Furthermore, this is what I get when I log `time`

```
{
  days: 0,
  hours: 0,
  minutes: 0,
  seconds: 14,
  milliseconds: 324,
  microseconds: 0,
  nanoseconds: 0
}
```

Comment: What  is author? Is it another date? Also, what is the difference between `message.channel` and `msg` you use to edit?

Comment: @David Buzatu `author` is ```let author = await db.fetch(`manage.${message.guild.id}.${user.id}`)```

Comment: `message.channel` is the first message that will be sent, `msg` will be the edited version of `message.channel` after a period of `time.milliseconds`

Comment: So your `author` is something like a user in your database model, right? Why are you subtracting it from  `Date.now()`?

Comment: If I don’t have that, the command can be executed continuosly. No cool downs are set

Comment: According to [Official Docs on DateNow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now), it returns the milliseconds since 1970 (Epoch). `author` is an object (I suppose). How can you subtract from a number an object? Something is wrong with the logic there.

Also, where does your function go? Is it called inside a route of the `node` server?

Comment: I'm assuming what is fetched from the DB is the last time `Date` of when the command was last used. Could you please clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

****Edit the message after X MS****

There's a handy NPMJS package which you can use: [delay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/delay)

All I do here is implement the delay of when the message is edited. I would recommend console.logging `time.milliseconds * 1000` and checking its output.

```js
const delay = require('delay');

let timeout = 15000;//(15 seconds)

if (author !== null && timeout - (Date.now() - author) > 0) {
   let time = ms(timeout - (Date.now() - author));
     
   const cooldownMessage = await message.channel.send("Cool down in effect");
   await delay(time.milliseconds * 1000);
   cooldownMessage.edit("Cool down is over");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing me with the answer, but unfortunately, it did not edit after the `time.milliseconds * 1000` and it does not give me an error. Any fix for this code?

Comment: Add the following to your code then test it again: `process.on("unhandledRejection", err => console.error(err))`